# Pacific Northwest - how can I find about sea Bioluminescence events?

Tags: sea, canada, plants

I happened to stumble upon the last bits of a [bioluminescence](https://www.fraserriverkeeper.ca/the_secret_night_lives_of_plankton) event on [Cortes Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortes_Island), in BC, in 2011.  It was absolutely amazing, but most of it had happened in the previous days.

I'd love to go paddleboarding at night in one of these, but I am not quite sure how one finds out about these.  Most of the time, there is not that much plankton activity, at least to my understanding, even in season.

Although... some do claim it's predictable(from first link):

> The best places and times to see bioluminescence in action locally this summer will be any beach without a lot of light pollution and around the days surrounding the new moon, when the night sky will be darker.

And, again, a kayaker blog about [Puget Sound for 2022](https://nckayaks.com/summer-2022-bioluminescence-in-puget-sound-best-dates/), but for people who have attempted catching these, how reliable are *predictions*?

This is sometimes covered in the [news](https://www.king5.com/article/travel/destinations/explore-the-pnw/washington-coast-blue-glow-bioluminescence/281-893866ce-432e-4533-91a7-0d4deebcb606), but I also am not going to watch local news that much, just in case they cover it.

The areas easiest to access for me would be Vancouver/Sunshine Coast/Vancouver Island (easiest to more complicated).

Any suggestions on how best to find out about these events?

This [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/371722474201202/) also looks promising.  Any other ideas/suggestions?

[image: Bioluminescence at Scripps Pier]

(Bioluminescence at Scripps Pier, California, CC-licensed courtesy Flickr & KevinKeyPhotography.com)

Comment: My understanding is that we can't predict it until it's basically happening. We get in in Southern California sometimes and it has always seemed random

Comment: My experience (in the Puget Sound) matches what’s described in that kayaker blog: you’re likely to see bioluminescence when it’s hot and dark.  The darkness is easy enough to predict, since we know the phases of the moon and the timing of sunsets.  Heat is not easy to predict much in advance.  I also feel like it’s easier to see in still water (which might just be a temperature thing again), so calm bays and inlets are a good choice

Comment: that quote doesn't predict when bioluminescence will be happening or be brighter, but when you will be more able to see it if it is happening. Perhaps it always happens and all that changes is your ability to see it, but perhaps you require both a dark sky and for the luminescence to be happening.

Comment: Well, found someone asking if late April was a good time, on Vancouver Island.  One person, citing his son who frequently watches them said it was too early, so there seems to be a strong correlation with water temperature.  Which some sites do [track](https://www.seatemperature.org/north-america/canada/).